# Drop column labels from empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an operation that *might* return an empty data frame. The result then still has column labels.

Small example

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]])
>>> res = df.tail(-1)
>>> res
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1]
Index: []
```

I want to modify this dataframe in-place to be equal to `pd.DataFrame()`.

I tried:

```
>>> res.columns = []
[...]
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 0 elements
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out while typing the question.

```
res.drop(res.columns, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```